# Android Twitter - Pull down Refresh and hiding tab

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, android-custom-view, android-scrollview

How can I synchronize the scroll of list-view with other views ,also I want to implements pull-down-refresh just like twitter application.
In twitter application, while scrolling up the list-view, tab bar and bottom view get hides and in case of scrolling down pull-down-refresh views comes.

**Below Image represents : No scrolling of list**
[image: No scrolling of list]

**Below Image represents : scrolling up the list : tab bar and bottom views get hides**
[image: Scrolling up the list]!

**Below Image represents : scrolling down the list : pull-down-refresh comes**
[image: Scrolling down the list]!

Comment: Have you find a solution finally ? I will be intrested if yes :)

Comment: Sorry, but I had not yet tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also looking for this kind of features and i came across this library at github..
have a look.. this might helps.. :)

*see link https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView

i am currently studying this library for our application..

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) library for Pull To Refresh functionality.

Comment: I already referred this library. Thanks for reply.
Is there any sample for synchronizing scroll of list-view with two or more views/layouts.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. Can you please explain it further?
Also, mark this as the answer if this library works for you. thanks :)

Comment: I have edited the images. Please reply if you get my question.Thanks :)